# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.8, mlflow

I have this class for the evaluation of a deep learning model :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import mlflow
import mlflow.keras

class Evaluation:
    def __init__(self, config: EvaluationConfig):
        self.config = config
    
    def _valid_generator(self):

        datagenerator_kwargs = dict(
            rescale = 1./255,
            validation_split=0.30
        )

        dataflow_kwargs = dict(
            target_size=self.config.params_image_size[:-1],
            batch_size=self.config.params_batch_size,
            interpolation="bilinear"
        )

        valid_datagenerator = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
            **datagenerator_kwargs
        )

        self.valid_generator = valid_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
            directory=self.config.training_data,
            subset="validation",
            shuffle=False,
            **dataflow_kwargs
        )


    @staticmethod
    def load_model(path: Path) -> tf.keras.Model:
        return tf.keras.models.load_model(path)
    

    def evaluation(self):
        self.model = self.load_model(self.config.path_of_model)
        self._valid_generator()
        self.score = self.model.evaluate(self.valid_generator)
        self.save_score()

    def save_score(self):
        scores = {"loss": self.score[0], "accuracy": self.score[1]}
        save_json(path=Path("scores.json"), data=scores)

    
    def log_into_mlflow(self):
        mlflow.set_registry_uri(self.config.mlflow_uri)
        tracking_url_type_store = urlparse(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()).scheme
        
        with mlflow.start_run():
            mlflow.log_params(self.config.all_params)
            mlflow.log_metrics(
                {"loss": self.score[0], "accuracy": self.score[1]}
            )
            # Model registry does not work with file store
            if tracking_url_type_store != "file":

                # Register the model
                # There are other ways to use the Model Registry, which depends on the use case,
                # please refer to the doc for more information:                # https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#api-workflow
                mlflow.keras.log_model(self.model, "model", registered_model_name="model")
            else:
                mlflow.keras.log_model(self.model, "model")
```

and when I try to run my evaluation code :

```
try:
    config = ConfigurationManager()
    eval_config = config.get_evaluation_config()
    evaluation = Evaluation(config=eval_config)
    evaluation.evaluation()
    evaluation.log_into_mlflow()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

(No need to see config it's basic)
I get the error :

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute '__version__'
```

coming from the line `mlflow.keras.log_model` from the method `log_into_mlflow`

For information I'm using a conda venv with python 3.8 and tensorflow version 2.13.0

I assume it might be coming from a conflict between mlflow.keras and tf.keras ? But if someone knows why I would appreciate it. Thank you